# How can I change label color for any entry in Files, using scripts?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, pantheon

Pantheon-Files has a feature of assigning color to file/directory names displayed. I want to make a script in Bash/Python to do the same automatically.

Answer (score 4):

### Low-level sqlite approach

The file-color associations are stored in the `~/.config/marlin/marlin.db` sqlite database. You can try to reverse-engineer the format, as far as I have seen, there is one table `tags`, as seen in the dump:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                   uri TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                   color INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                   tags TEXT NULL,
                   content_type TEXT,
                   modified_time INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                   dir TEXT );
```

#### Update/delete file color

So basically you need to either the color already in the base as in

```
UPDATE tags set color=1 WHERE uri = 'file:///home/user/test'
```

changed the color of the file `~/test` to yellow (1).
Colors seem to be `0` (no color) and `1…9` (yellow, orange, etc. as shown in the file *Properties* dialog).

If you want to delete the color, you only have to set `color=0`.

#### Set file color

If there is no entry for the file specified, you should create it with some housekeeping:

- `id` might be NULL as in auto-assigned,
- `uri` is the URI of the file of which you want to change the color
- `tags` = NULL as in nothing special for now,
- `content_type` you might find this with the `file` utility,
- `modified_time` seems to be a simple Unix time stamp,
- `dir` I don't really know but the parent directory seems to be a safe bet.

This line seems to work and has set the color of `~/new_file` not present in the database before to green (4):

```
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (NULL, 'file:///home/user/new_file', 4, NULL, 'text/plain', 1481148148, 'file:///home/user');
```

However, be careful and double-check this with the source code of `pantheon-files` as this might render your database inconsistent. The relevant source file seems to be `pantheon-files-daemon/marlind-tagging.vala`.