# How does Pantheon Files store color tags?

Tags: pantheon-files, metadata

When I tag a file with a color in Pantheon Files, where is the tag recorded?

[image]

I guessed it may be stored in a hidden file in the same directory (similar to what Windows and macOS do), but I did not find such file.

Answer (score 2):

The file-color associations are stored in the `~/.config/marlin/marlin.db` sqlite database.

This should answer your question as well: [How can I change label color for any entry in Files, using scripts?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7963/how-can-i-change-label-color-for-any-entry-in-files-using-scripts)